# Android Camera Preview question

Tags: android, camera

I am writing a program to study Android Camera functions.
Now, I have some problems about Camera preview operation:

My program will create a surfaceview object in the main activity (ActivityMain)'s onCreate() function and then set it to the content.

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    m_surface = new MyCameraSurface(this);        
    // remove title bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);        
    setContentView(m_surface);
```

Then startPreview() will be called when surfaceChanged() is running.

```
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    Log.d(TAG, "*** surfaceChanged >>>>> ***");
    Log.d(TAG, "format=" + format + ", width=" + width + ", height=" + height);

    if(m_control.IsCameraClosed() == false) {
        if(m_control.IsPreviewRun() == false) {             
            m_control.startPreview();
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "*** surfaceChanged <<<<< ***");
}
```

My problem is: at the beginning my program always receives "GetNextPreviewFrame Error/1 frame:0x0, buffer:0x0" error:

```
07-22 06:47:46.727: DEBUG/MyCameraSurface(2313): *** surfaceChanged <<<<< ***
07-22 06:47:46.735: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1276): commiting overlay changes
07-22 06:47:46.735: INFO/TIOverlay(1276): Nothing to do!
07-22 06:47:46.735: INFO/ActivityManager(1276): Displayed activity com.hykwok.CameraEffect/.ActivityMain: 7866 ms (total 7866 ms)
07-22 06:47:47.792: ERROR/CameraHal(1052): GetNextPreviewFrame Error/1 frame:0x0, buffer:0x0
07-22 06:47:48.477: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1276): GC freed 2299 objects / 119216 bytes in 143ms
07-22 06:47:48.793: ERROR/CameraHal(1052): GetNextPreviewFrame Error/1 frame:0x0, buffer:0x0
07-22 06:47:49.794: ERROR/CameraHal(1052): GetNextPreviewFrame Error/1 frame:0x0, buffer:0x0
07-22 06:47:50.794: ERROR/CameraHal(1052): GetNextPreviewFrame Error/1 frame:0x0, buffer:0x0
```

However, when I switch to another activity (ActivityCameraSetting) and then go back to the main activity, the output becomes normal.

Could anyone give some suggestion to me to fix it?

I am using Motorola Milestone. Firmware version is 2.1-update1 and build number is SHOLS_U2.02.36.0.

I am not sure other Android phones whether have this problem or not.

Another question is:
Is it possible to get preview frame data by the preview callback function without set surfaceview holder?

Thank you for your help.

Source codes can be downloaded from here:

[Source codes link](http://code.google.com/p/android-simple-camera-effect/downloads/list)

Comment: I've faced similar issues with Motorola devices. Moreover, sometimes it's just easy to make their phones crash (I mean, not to cause exception in Java, but reset the device as well). I've gave up and make some tricky workarounds. Per my understanding it's definitely BUG in Motorola Camera HAL. However I'm able to observe that the issue still not fixed on droid X. I would suggest You to try another device (HTC or Samsung) - I'm about to be sure that Yours code will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell exactly what the issue is without more of the logs, I would guess based on the 0x0 bit that either your surface isn't fully created yet or the camera preview size isn't set properly.  One suggestion I would have is to add:

```
m_holder.setFormat(PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
```

to your MyCameraSurface constructor.  I was getting some similarly ambiguous errors re: CameraHal and that seemed to resolve the bulk of them. Can you post a bit more of your logs?